# Increase bitmap size without scaling image

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I would like to increase the size of a Bitmap in my Android application.

It sounds like a very simple operation but I cannot find how to do so anywhere.
Here is an image to illustrate what I am trying to achieve here:
[image: The two bitmaps I'd like to have]

Basically, I'd like to create a new bitmap that has the same width as the original, but a bigger height. The background of the (new) extra pixels can be black, white or transparent.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some like this should do.

```java
// Create a Canvas to draw to
Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas();
// Create a Bitmap to back the Canvas of the new size
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(X, Z, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmapCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

// Calculate the new position of bitmap
// Middle of new Z dimension minus half the original height to centre it.
int newY = (Z / 2) - (Y / 2);

// Draw original bitmap to new location
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(origBitmap, 0, newY, paint);
```